# How can I store a list of properties (not their values)?

Tags: python

I have a class with some properties. I would like to store a list of the properties of an instance of this class like so:

```
obj = MyClass()
prop_list = [ obj.prop1, obj.prop2, obj.prop3, obj.prop1, obj.prop3 ]
```

in such way that

```
prop_list[0] = something
```

would invoke the property setter (not necessarily with the same syntax of course). Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Store the names of the properties instead and use `setattr`:

```
obj = MyClass()
prop_list = [ "prop1", "prop2", "prop3", "prop1", "prop3" ]
setattr(obj, prop_list[0], something)
```

If you really need the item assignment syntax, this is also possible with a custom class:

```
class CustomPropertyList(object):
    def __init__(self, obj, names):
        self.obj = obj
        self.property_names = list(names)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.obj, self.property_names[item])

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        setattr(self.obj, self.property_names[item], value)

prop_list = CustomPropertyList(obj, ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3", "prop1", "prop3"])
prop_list[0] = something
```

Comment: In the second to last line, you forgot to pass a leading `obj` argument to `CustomPropertyList()`. Also, if you'd change the definition `def __init__(self, obj, names):` to `def __init__(self, obj, *names):` it would be unnecessary to explicitly create a list of property names when calling the constructor, i.e. `CustomPropertyList(obj, "prop1", "prop2", "prop3", "prop1", "prop3")` would work.

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
getter = [ lambda x=x: getattr(obj, x) for x in ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'] ]
setter = [ lambda v, x=x: setattr(obj, x, v) for x in ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'] ]
```

then use it like:

```
getter[0]()
```

that will return the value of `obj.prop1`...

similarly you can use the `setter` to set new properties:

```
setter[1]('test')
```

will create `obj.prop2='test'`